# Mostrar archivo pdf en ventana modal

Tags: php

quiero mostrar un pdf generado de una factura en un modal, y esto quiero hacerlo para que el usuario pueda enviar por email si desea la misma, y hacerlo ni bien se emite la misma.
El caso es que es un sistema en un webhosting en la nube, por lo que no descargo cada factura.
Quiero mostrarla al emitirla para imprimirla y/o enviarla por email/whatsapp o bien descargarla.

Actualmente uso fpdf pero se ven simbolos en la pantalla.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces de que manera se podria lograr esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente tengo este codigo:

```
        $('.modal-body').load('/views/modules/facta/imprimeA.php? 
          id='+data,function(){
          $('#myModalPDF').modal({show:true});
      });
```

Me dirijo a un fichero php con el id de factura, y obtengo los datos.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Vuelo a editar la pregunta

```js
$('.modal-body').load('contentPDF.php?id='+data,function(){
    $('#myModalPDF').modal({show:true});
});
```

Y en contentPDF.php tengo el iframe:

```
      <iframe src="/views/modules/facta/imprimeA.php?id="+<?php $_GET['id']; 
    ?>+" style="border: none;">

    </iframe>
```

Y de hecho funciono. Pero se ve chiquito Y no se ven las opciones que mencionaba anteriormente.:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿ya miraste donde te estas guiando con inspeccionar el código a ver como lo muestra?.

Comment: Entiendo que un pdf no es contenido html. Encontre que puedo usar un iframe.. Puede ser?

Comment: Si, puedes usar un iframe para mostrar otros contenidos en tu web.

Comment: Entonces como indico que cargue el pdf en el iframe?

Comment: Tal vez este link te resulte util https://pdfobject.com/. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias..ya edite la pregunta..Solo me falta que aparezca el listado de opciones..Imprimir y descargar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes el archivo PDF en línea y está disponible para todo internet (sin autenticación en tu storage), puedes usar un `iframe` definiendo la fuente con ayuda de Google Drive, tendrás los controles del documento como si fuera Google Drive y es demasiado práctico. Además de un botón para abrirlo desde una nueva pestaña con más opciones como imprimir.

En tu HTML solo debes de tener el `iframe` de la siguiente manera, donde `$file` contiene la ruta donde tienes el archivo PDF:

```html
<iframe src!="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url={{ $file }}&embedded=true" frameborder="0" >
```

Comment: No sabes porque llama dos veces al archivo imprimeA.php?